# Laravel API Consumption

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, guzzle

What is the best way of creating and consuming API in `Laravel`?
I am writing the API with `Laravel` and `testing` with `postman`, but then I need to consume the API in the same project. The reason for the API is for other developers (e.g mobile dev) to have access to it.

I am currently using `Guzzle Client` but there is the need to consume these API with another package, framework, etc
Guzzle Client is one, but I need another option.

Comment: what's wrong with Guzzle which means you need another option? It's not really clear. BTW Recommendations for libraries are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, see point 4 of that article to understand why. But the obvious one for making HTTP requests is cURL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel does provide a wrapper around the Guzzle HTTP client.

If you are making the API requests inside your controllers, this might be a better option, as it is more expressive than Guzzle.

You can find more details here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client